# Wordpress (Woocommerce extension) - Create new order programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I want to create a new order programmatically.

Workflow is simple: After submitting simple form, user will be created and along with that, a new order.

I managed to create a new user and user_id is returned, now I need to assign a new order all in one step.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which way did you end up using?

Answer (score 16):

Here's how I programmatically create my orders. I largely followed WC_Checkout::create_order() from @pavel's suggestion above.  This is directly from a plugin I'm writing so you'll have to adjust where the source data comes form.

```
// build order data
$order_data = array(
    'post_name'     => 'order-' . date_format($order_date, 'M-d-Y-hi-a'), //'order-jun-19-2014-0648-pm'
    'post_type'     => 'shop_order',
    'post_title'    => 'Order &ndash; ' . date_format($order_date, 'F d, Y @ h:i A'), //'June 19, 2014 @ 07:19 PM'
    'post_status'   => 'wc-completed',
    'ping_status'   => 'closed',
    'post_excerpt'  => $order->note,
    'post_author'   => $account->user_id,
    'post_password' => uniqid( 'order_' ),   // Protects the post just in case
    'post_date'     => date_format($order_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e'), //'order-jun-19-2014-0648-pm'
    'comment_status' => 'open'
);

// create order
$order_id = wp_insert_post( $order_data, true );

if ( is_wp_error( $order_id ) ) {

    $order->errors = $order_id;

} else {

    $order->imported = true;

    // add a bunch of meta data
    add_post_meta($order_id, 'transaction_id', $order->transaction_id, true); 
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method_title', 'Import', true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_order_total', $order->gross, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', $account->user_id, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_completed_date', date_format( $order_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e'), true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_order_currency', $order->currency, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_paid_date', date_format( $order_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e'), true);

    // billing info
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_1', $order->address_line_1, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_2', $order->address_line_2, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_city', $order->city, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_state', $order->state, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_postcode', $order->zip, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_country', $order->country, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_email', $order->from_email, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_first_name', $order->first_name, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_last_name', $order->last_name, true);
    add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_phone', $order->phone, true);

    // get product by item_id
    $product = get_product_by_sku( $order->item_id );

    if( $product ) {

        // add item
        $item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, array(
            'order_item_name'       => $product->get_title(),
            'order_item_type'       => 'line_item'
        ) );

        if ( $item_id ) {

            // add item meta data
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_qty', 1 ); 
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_tax_class', $product->get_tax_class() );
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', $product->ID );
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_variation_id', '' );
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal', wc_format_decimal( $order->gross ) );
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', wc_format_decimal( $order->gross ) );
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_tax', wc_format_decimal( 0 ) );
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal_tax', wc_format_decimal( 0 ) );

        }

        // set order status as completed
        wp_set_object_terms( $order_id, 'completed', 'shop_order_status' );

        // if downloadable 
        if( $product->is_downloadable() ) {

            // add downloadable permission for each file
            $download_files = $product->get_files();
            foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {
                wc_downloadable_file_permission( $download_id, $product->id, new WC_Order( $order_id ) );
            }

        }

    } else {

        $order->errors = 'Product SKU (' . $order->$item_id . ') not found.';
    }
}


function get_product_by_sku( $sku ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );

    if ( $product_id ) return new WC_Product( $product_id );

    return null;
}
```

#### Order Class

The is the interim class I use to store the orders before importing into WordPress / WooCommerce.

```
class ImportOrder
{
    // public vars
    public $date;
    public $time;
    public $time_zone;
    public $first_name;
    public $middle_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $type;
    public $status;
    public $currency;
    public $gross;
    public $fee;
    public $net;
    public $note;
    public $to_email;
    public $from_email;
    public $transaction_id;
    public $counterparty_status;
    public $address_status;
    public $item_title;
    public $item_id;
    public $address_line_1;
    public $address_line_2;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zip;
    public $country;
    public $phone;
    public $imported;
    public $errors;
}
```

#### Add Order

The data here is imported from a PayPal CSV download of historical transactions. The $row variable represents one row in the CSV. You can adjust this to suit your needs.

```
function add_import_order( $row ) {

    // create new order
    $order = new ImportOrder();

    // done this before?
    $order->exists = order_exists( $row[PayPalCols::TRANSACTION_ID] );

    // add a bunch of fields
    $order->date = $row[PayPalCols::DATE];
    $order->time = $row[PayPalCols::TIME];
    $order->time_zone = $row[PayPalCols::TIME_ZONE];
    $order->type = $row[PayPalCols::TYPE];
    $order->status = $row[PayPalCols::STATUS];
    $order->currency = $row[PayPalCols::CURRENCY];
    $order->gross = $row[PayPalCols::GROSS];
    $order->fee = $row[PayPalCols::FEE];
    $order->net = $row[PayPalCols::NET];
    $order->note = $row[PayPalCols::NOTE];
    $order->from_email = $row[PayPalCols::FROM_EMAIL];
    $order->to_email = $row[PayPalCols::TO_EMAIL];
    $order->transaction_id = $row[PayPalCols::TRANSACTION_ID];
    $order->counterparty_status = $row[PayPalCols::COUNTERPARTY_STATUS];
    $order->address_status = $row[PayPalCols::ADDRESS_STATUS];
    $order->item_title = $row[PayPalCols::ITEM_TITLE];
    $order->item_id = $row[PayPalCols::ITEM_ID];
    $order->address_line_1 = utf8_encode( $row[PayPalCols::ADDRESS_LINE_1] );
    $order->address_line_2 = utf8_encode( $row[PayPalCols::ADDRESS_LINE_2] );
    $order->city = utf8_encode( $row[PayPalCols::TOWN_CITY] );
    $order->state = utf8_encode( $row[PayPalCols::STATE] );
    $order->zip = utf8_encode( $row[PayPalCols::ZIP] );
    $order->country = utf8_encode( $row[PayPalCols::COUNTRY] );
    $order->phone = utf8_encode( $row[PayPalCols::PHONE] );

    return $order;

}
```

Comment: very nice. Shame there is no api endpoint for this in their REST API.
I hav to customise my checkout in a single page app and can't use the standard Woocommerce checkout page. Adding  the products manually works for me. Ill turn you code in to a service. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, glad it was helpful to you. In the context of WordPress or WooCommerce, I'm curious, what do you mean by turn the code into a service?

Comment: Ah nothing more than a service call with an associative array as param so that can pass a dynamic set of params and reuse it more easily

Comment: Without upgrading to 2.2 woocommerce is this the only way to create the order programatically? Seems like there should be a better way, but I guess that's what they introduced in 2.2 ...

Comment: Also, how do you go about creating the order and storing it into the $order variable. That's the main part I'm having trouble with... Seems as though WC_Order doesn't have everything I need it to.

Comment: Hi @DavidHahn, I have updated the answer to include how I populate the $order variable. As far as if this is only way to create orders, I am not sure, but it works. As you mentioned there should be a better way, but the WooCommerce API doesn't offer much in this regard, unless it was introduced in 2.2, which I haven't dug into yet. Do you know more regarding that?

Comment: @jibby it seems as though they have added a few helper functions to create orders such as `wc_create_order` in 2.2. In our case it would be a pain to upgrade so we're stuck with this way for now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Could you please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526268/sql-query-to-download-order-report-in-woocommerce .

Answer (score 6):

For creating New order, You will have to create Object of `WC_Order`, If you working outside WooCommerce or in `function.php` then, First Define Global `$woocommerce` variable.

So, There will be just 2 line of Code.

```
global $woocommerce;

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
```

Hope, It will help You.

Answer (score 6):

As of WooCommerce 2.2 (or maybe 2.1 I'm not 100% sure) there is now a function specifically designed for this.

```
wc_create_order( $args = array() )
```

with the following default arguments.

```
$default_args = array(
    'status'        => '',
    'customer_id'   => null,
    'customer_note' => null,
    'order_id'      => 0
);
```

You can see the whole function in the `includes/wc-core-functions.php` file.

Comment: WooCommerce 2.1 has not `wc_create_order`

Comment: With version 2.3 coming out soon, I hope no one is still using 2.1!

Comment: Could you please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526268/sql-query-to-download-order-report-in-woocommerce .

Comment: This function always create a new order and not checking order_id.

Comment: Did you set the `order_id` parameter? If the order exists the `wp_update_post()` is called instead of `wp_insert_post()`. You can see the `[wc_create_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_order.html#51-127) here.

Answer (score 6):

There's a much easier way of doing it, using `wc_create_order()`. Here's an example, which also adds shipping and product line items. It also creates a Woocommerce subscription, but you can ignore that part for a normal product, the same code will work.

```
function create_test_sub() {

    $email = 'test@test.com';

    $start_date = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'Jeremy',
        'last_name'  => 'Test',
        'company'    => '',
        'email'      => $email,
        'phone'      => '777-777-777-777',
        'address_1'  => '31 Main Street',
        'address_2'  => '', 
        'city'       => 'Auckland',
        'state'      => 'AKL',
        'postcode'   => '12345',
        'country'    => 'AU'
    );

    $default_password = wp_generate_password();

    if (!$user = get_user_by('login', $email)) $user = wp_create_user( $email, $default_password, $email );

    // I've used one product with multiple variations

    $parent_product = wc_get_product(22998);

    $args = array(
        'attribute_billing-period' => 'Yearly',
        'attribute_subscription-type' => 'Both'
    );

    $product_variation = $parent_product->get_matching_variation($args);

    $product = wc_get_product($product_variation);  

    // Each variation also has its own shipping class

    $shipping_class = get_term_by('slug', $product->get_shipping_class(), 'product_shipping_class');

    WC()->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
    $shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();

    // I have some logic for selecting which shipping method to use; your use case will likely be different, so figure out the method you need and store it in $selected_shipping_method

    $selected_shipping_method = $shipping_methods['free_shipping'];

    $class_cost = $selected_shipping_method->get_option('class_cost_' . $shipping_class->term_id);

    $quantity = 1;

    // As far as I can see, you need to create the order first, then the sub

    $order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id' => $user->id));

    $order->add_product( $product, $quantity, $args);
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

    $order->add_shipping((object)array (
        'id' => $selected_shipping_method->id,
        'label'    => $selected_shipping_method->title,
        'cost'     => (float)$class_cost,
        'taxes'    => array(),
        'calc_tax'  => 'per_order'
    ));

    $order->calculate_totals();

    $order->update_status("completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);

    // Order created, now create sub attached to it -- optional if you're not creating a subscription, obvs

    // Each variation has a different subscription period

    $period = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period( $product );
    $interval = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval( $product );

    $sub = wcs_create_subscription(array('order_id' => $order->id, 'billing_period' => $period, 'billing_interval' => $interval, 'start_date' => $start_date));

    $sub->add_product( $product, $quantity, $args);
    $sub->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $sub->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

    $sub->add_shipping((object)array (
        'id' => $selected_shipping_method->id,
        'label'    => $selected_shipping_method->title,
        'cost'     => (float)$class_cost,
        'taxes'    => array(),
        'calc_tax'  => 'per_order'
    ));

    $sub->calculate_totals();

    WC_Subscriptions_Manager::activate_subscriptions_for_order($order);

    print "<a href='/wp-admin/post.php?post=" . $sub->id . "&action=edit'>Sub created! Click here to edit</a>";
}
```

Comment: hello jeremy thank you very much for your information but your subscription code is not working , could you suggest me where i need to put this code so that it work .

Answer (score 4):

have a look at my solution:
[creating Woocommerce order with line_item programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581467/solved-creating-woocommerce-order-with-line-item-programatically)

Works like a charm and goes to the correct WC class that is used by the new REST API

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there are no easy way to do this I'm afraid.

You need to add the order post using `wp_insert_post();` and then add all the meta data using `update_post_meta()`. You then need to add the using `woocommerce_add_order_item()` and `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta()`. Lasty you need to set the order status using `wp_set_object_terms()`.

It's quite a lot of steps and pitfalls. You need to check your database carefully and add all the data and meta data you need to process and complete the order.

Comment: Could you please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526268/sql-query-to-download-order-report-in-woocommerce .

Answer (score 0):

in woocommerce WC_Checkout class has a "create_order" method. You can clone WC_Checkout class, give it another name, change the code of the method for your purposes and call like

```
include 'path_to_Cloned_WC_Checkout';
$chk = new Cloned_WC_Checkout();
$chk->create_order();
```

in form handler

Answer (score 0):

maybe this way..

```
    function insert_order_to_db($seller,$order_date){
        global $wpdb;
        $result   = $wpdb->query(
            "
            INSERT INTO `wp_posts`(`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`)

            VALUES (
            17188,
            $seller,
            '".date_format($order_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e')."',
            '".date_format($order_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e')."',
            'no',
            'Order &ndash;". date_format($order_date, 'F d, Y @ h:i A')."',
            'noxp',
            'wc-completed',
            'open',
            'close',
            '".uniqid( 'order_' )."',
            'order-". date_format($order_date, 'M-d-Y-hi-a')."',
            '',
            '',
            '2017-07-24',
            '2017-07-24',
            '',
            0,
            '',
            0,
            'shop_order',
            '',
            0)

            "
        );
        $order_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
        return $order_id;
    }
function proccess_order_meta(){
        $date     = date_create("2017-07-24");
        $order_id = insert_order_to_db(194816,$date);
        if( is_wp_error( $order_id ) ){
            $order->errors = $order_id;
        }
        else
        {
            $order_id = 17188;
            add_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method_title', 'پرداخت آنلاین', true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, '_order_total', 30000, true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user',  194816, true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, '_completed_date', date_format( $date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e'), true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, '_paid_date', date_format( $date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e'), true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_email', "mavaezi46@gmail.com", true);
            add_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_first_name', "علی", true);

        }

    }
    proccess_order_meta();
```

Answer (score 0):

that line for downloadables is fire.
my files weren't showing up under user downloads without it.

```
// if downloadable 
if( $product->is_downloadable() ) {

 // add downloadable permission for each file
        $download_files = $product->get_files();
        foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {
            wc_downloadable_file_permission( $download_id, $product->id, new WC_Order( $order_id ) );
        }

    }
```