# Call to a member function get_order() on a non-object... while calling wc_create_order() in function.php to create new order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

when I create a new order in function.php of the theme using woocommerce plugin

```
$order = wc_create_order();
```

It shows me an error as

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_order() on a non-object in ../wc-order-functions.php on line 58
```

& when I open the file it contains

```
return WC()->order_factory->get_order( $the_order );
```

I got the documentation as

```
    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product( get_product( '2319' ), 2 );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
    $order->calculate_totals();
```

given on github but not working.

Please help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is like `return wc_get_order( $order_id );` for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: return WC()->order_factory->get_order( $the_order ); is defined in core file of woocommerce which I can't change.

Comment: I create new order with wc_create_order(); & it generate orderid in admin but its showing fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $order = wc_create_order();
 $custaddress=array(
       // array fields here
    );
        $order->add_product( get_product( '12' ), 2 ); //(get_product with id and next is for quantity)
        $order->set_address( $custaddress, 'billing' );
        $order->set_address( $custaddress, 'shipping' );
        $order->add_coupon('Fresher','10','2'); // accepted param $couponcode, $couponamount,$coupon_tax
        $order->calculate_totals();
```

Call this above code with your function then it will work accordingly.

**Note : code is not working with earlier version 2.2.**

Comment: I'm using WordPress 4.4.2 & still its throwing Fatal error

Comment: I am talking about woocommerce plugin not wordpress

Comment: It's woocommerce 2.5.2

Comment: here is the link from which I got the code.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581467/creating-woocommerce-order-with-line-item-programatically