# Add a product programmatically to WooCommerce subscription changing its name & price

Tags: php, methods, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying to programmatically add an existing product to an order but change the name and price, just for this order.

I can add the existing product easily enough using:

```
$subscription->add_product( get_product( '969' ), 1);
```

How can I set a custom name and price for that?

If I can set that I then know I can run the following to recalculate the totals:

```
$subscription->calculate_totals();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change product price and name added to a subscription try the following:

```
$product   = wc_get_product('969');
$quantity  = 1;
$new_price = 100; // (Excluding taxes).
$new_name  = 'New name';

// Add the product
$item_id  = $subscription->add_product( $product, $quantity );

// Get the instance of WC_Order_Item_Product Object from item Id
$item = $subscription->get_item( $item_id, false ); // Get the 

// Change name and price
$item->set_name( $new_name ); // set new name
$item->set_subtotal( $new_price * $item_quantity ); // set new price

// Calculate item taxes
$item->calculate_taxes( array(
    'country'  => $subscription->get_billing_country() ? $subscription->get_billing_country() : $subscription->get_shipping_country(),
    'state'    => $subscription->get_billing_state() ? $subscription->get_billing_state() : $subscription->get_shipping_state(),
    'postcode' => $subscription->get_billing_postcode() ? $subscription->get_billing_postcode() : $subscription->get_shipping_postcode(),
    'city'     => $subscription->get_billing_city() ? $subscription->get_billing_city() : $subscription->get_shipping_city(),
) );

$item->save(); // Save item

$subscription->calculate_totals(); // Refresh subscription totals and save.
```

It should work.

Related: [Programmatically created WooCommerce order have no tax for new users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662176/programmatically-created-woocommerce-order-have-no-tax-for-new-users/64670045#64670045)