# Create programmatically a "completed" order without sending email to customer in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I use this code for new order and set complete status.

After it, woocommerce send automatic email to buyer.

But I want dont send this email.

How I can?

```
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->set_customer_id($userId);

foreach($_POST['basket'] as $prod){
    $order->add_product(get_product($prod['id']), $prod['count']);
}

$order->set_address($address, 'billing');
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->update_status("completed", 'TEST', TRUE);
```

Note: I dont want disable send email from wp-admin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the function `get_product()` is obsolete and replaced by `wc_get_product()` instead.

To avoid notifications to customer, you can set user ID to `0` first, then after updating order status to "complete", you can set the user address and the real user ID as follows:

```
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->set_customer_id(0);

foreach($_POST['basket'] as $prod){
    $order->add_product( wc_get_product($prod['id']), $prod['count']);
}

$order->calculate_totals();
$order->update_status("completed", 'TEST', TRUE);

$order->set_address($address, 'billing'); // set address
$order->set_customer_id($userId); // Set user ID
$order_id = $order->save(); // Save to database (get order ID)

// Allow resending new order email
add_filter('woocommerce_new_order_email_allows_resend', '__return_true' );

// Resend new order email
WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );

// Disable resending new order email
add_filter('woocommerce_new_order_email_allows_resend', '__return_false' );
```

Tested and works.

The only thing is that you will get 2 times "New order" notification sent to the admin *(The second email will be set with the correct customer address details)*.

Related:

- [Allow re-sending New Order Notification in WooCommerce 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604256/allow-re-sending-new-order-notification-in-woocommerce-5/66604522#66604522)
- [Create an order programmatically with line items in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581467/create-an-order-programmatically-with-line-items-in-woocommerce/55437588#55437588)