# WooCommerce create an order programmatically and redirect to payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For WooCommerce i'm lookin' for a solution to create an order programmaticly (my site just has 1 homepage with some fields) to order.

After products are added with a checkbox i'd like to create an order and redirect to the payment method.

Creating an order is almost done with this answer, but how do i start a payment?
[Wordpress (Woocommerce extension) - Create new order programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163251/wordpress-woocommerce-extension-create-new-order-programatically)

Comment: Great question indeed, I was also looking for the solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
if (isset($_POST['isOrder']) && $_POST['isOrder'] == 1) {
    $address = array(
        'first_name' => $_POST['notes']['domain'],
        'last_name'  => '',
        'company'    => $_POST['customer']['company'],
        'email'      => $_POST['customer']['email'],
        'phone'      => $_POST['customer']['phone'],
        'address_1'  => $_POST['customer']['address'],
        'address_2'  => '', 
        'city'       => $_POST['customer']['city'],
        'state'      => '',
        'postcode'   => $_POST['customer']['postalcode'],
        'country'    => 'NL'
    );

    $order = wc_create_order();
    foreach ($_POST['product_order'] as $productId => $productOrdered) :
        $order->add_product( get_product( $productId ), 1 );
    endforeach;

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

    $order->calculate_totals();

    update_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', 'ideal' );
    update_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method_title', 'iDeal' );

    // Store Order ID in session so it can be re-used after payment failure
    WC()->session->order_awaiting_payment = $order->id;

    // Process Payment
    $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
    $result = $available_gateways[ 'ideal' ]->process_payment( $order->id );

    // Redirect to success/confirmation/payment page
    if ( $result['result'] == 'success' ) {

        $result = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', $result, $order->id );

        wp_redirect( $result['redirect'] );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be awesome if you also included javascript.

Comment: You saved my 2 weeks, with 900 usd, I cannot find more words to appreciate!

Comment: Hi.. I did exactly what was mentioned but i couldnt store the billing and shipping address. Can u please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668922/wc-create-not-setting-billing-or-shipping-address

Comment: I did respond on that @AlaksandarJesusGene. But you should also provide a print_r of your $_POST in your post.

Comment: Thank @Ronn0. I made a type and didnt work out. Its working now.

Comment: Hi.Can u take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716234/woocommerce-payment-gateway-initialize

Comment: Hi.Thanks I got it working. I mistook $result['result'] == ''success" as payment success.

Comment: Hi, if possible,  can u  please have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808859/creating-custom-post-type-and-items-with-woocommerce

Comment: What is $_post??

Comment: $result = $available_gateways[ 'ideal' ]->process_payment( $order->get_id() ); This is not working getting a error

Comment: @MaartendeWolf, you should use the right key for  $available_gateways[ 'ideal' ]; Check the key 'ideal';

Answer (score 0):

To skip the checkout page you can filter the add to cart url.

```
function so_31787244_redirect_to_checkout( $url ) {

    // Remove default cart message
    WC()->clear_messages();

    // Redirect to checkout
    $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_redirect', 'so_31787244_redirect_to_checkout' );
```

You could also pursue a plugin such as [One Page Checkout](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/)

Comment: I want to skip the cart and checkout page. For example, on my productpage people can fill their contact info and push button "Pay now". After that an order needs to be created and redirected to payment page (for example paypal.com).

Comment: I'm not sure why you are even using WooCommerce then. But, that said, this sounds pretty custom, maybe you can write a function that will create the order when PayPal validates the order. But it seems like a lot of work for little benefit. I think you'd be better off investing in an SSL cert and a premium PayPal plugin and accepting payment right on your site.