# WC_CREATE not setting billing or shipping address

Tags: woocommerce

favorite
I am trying to create a new order and my code as follows

```
{
        $products = $_POST['products'];
        $shipping_address = $_POST['shipping_address'];
        $billing_address = $_POST['billing_address'];
        global $woocommerce;
        $args = array(
            'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        );
        $order = wc_create_order($args);
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $order->add_product(get_product($product['id']), $product['quantity']);
        }
        $order->set_address($shipping_address, 'shipping');
        $order->set_address($billing_address, 'billing');
        $order->calculate_totals();
        wp_send_json(array("success" => true, "order" => $order));
    }
```

Questions

1.Shipping address and billing address are not updating. (Refer image). I am passing the fields as
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/
shown in billing and shipping.

2.I need to have custom field, like (preferred pickup date), how to add that field as meta_data to that order

3.How to get the newly created order_id i.e, successful or error

4. How to attach coupon to that totals

[image]

Comment: I don't tink the $_POST['shipping_address'] is filled with the correct information. You should use the right fields instead of an non existing array. For example, first name is set in $_POST['billing_first_name'] (by default). To help you better it would be helpful to get a print_r of your $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

1, You need to use `$order->save();` to save updates you make to the order.

2, Use `$order->update_meta_data( 'meta_field', $data );` and don't forget to `$order->save();`

3, You get the id from `$order` via `$order->get_id();`

4, Did not try coupon, but I am sure you will work that out.

Comment: $order->save() didnt work. Still by billing and shipping address are empty. I got your info on point 2. point 3: $order->id gave the information

Comment: Got it working. It was a typo and i mentioned everything as billing_first_name which was supposed to be only first_name. Thank you very much

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene hey, great that it is working. :)
Hm, $order->get_id() should work, I think $order->id will give you a PHP notice, but it still works.